# Цикл While (задание для новичка)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мы только начали проходить циклы while. А ещё преподаватель не объяснил, как пользоваться "sum" и "round". И я собирала этот код по кусочкам с форума. Но чего-то не хватает. Выкладываю задачу и лучший (на мой взгляд) вариант кода.

**Задача**

*Напишите программу, которая считывает числа, пока пользователь не введет 55. После ввода 55 прекратите чтение ввода, распечатайте, сколько чисел было введено, их общую сумму и среднее значение (округленную). Вы НЕ включаете в себя 55 в своих расчетах и печати каждого полученное значение на новой линии в порядке.*

**Код**

```py
number=int(input())
i = 0
while number < 55:
     i = i + 1
     s = sum(number)
     r = round(number)
print(i)
print(s)
print(r)
```

Comment: Не хватает строки `number=int(input())` в конце цикла. И сравнение должно быть `!= 55`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
num = int(input())
nums = []
while num !=  55:
    nums.append(num)
    num = int(input())

s = sum(nums)
length = len(nums)
print("len = ", length)
print("sum = ", s)
print("среднее = ", s / length)
```

Comment: в задаче среднее значение (округленную), а у вас там float получается. и возможно списки они ещё не проходили и нельзя аппендить